# GooglePortableChrome version 49.0.2623.112 How to disable download prompt?

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

How to disable prompt:

> This type of file can harm your computer. Do you want to
>   keep....anyway?

while downloading ms-outlook file

Used `GooglePortableChrome version 49.0.2623.112`

Below are the few screen shots.

Selenium using c#

[dowloading_vdn.ms-outlookfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJDOh.p)

[download_Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kxFZ.png)

Comment: You generally can't. Otherwise what's to stop a malicious entity from stopping that prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off phishing & malware warnings

The following steps will turn of phishing and malware warnings, as well as download warnings.

In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu Chrome menu.
Select Settings.
Click Show advanced settings.
Under "Privacy," uncheck the box "Protect you and your device from dangerous sites"

Comment: i am using GooglePortableChrome 49.0.2623.112 . the option "Protect you and your device from dangerous sites" is disabled.